# How to access sub-elements in current object within JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]
Above I have three banner elements that I want to mark as unread if they are clicked. I structured each banner so that they have a span element within a nested div as shown with the image below (the red dot comes from the span element):
[image]
My javascript for this function is the following code:
[image]
I am trying to add a class ".read-dot" to the ".dot" span element that will hide it. I would like to add this class to the ".dot" span element that is inside the div that the user would click on. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried accessing the this.$(".dot) to access the dot element of the current object that triggered the event, but I now see this syntax is incorrect. I am new to jQuery which is why I tried this; I also could not find the page most relevant to my question on the API doc.

Comment: Look up the jQuery `.find()` method. Also, post actual code, not images of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect tat `$(this).find(".dot").addClass("read-dot");` would do the trick. You might consider switching it all to jQuery or all to JavaScript and not mix the two when possible.

Comment: yes, post actual code, not images of code.

Comment: @Twisty That worked perfectly-thank you. Also, why is it preferred to post the actual code and not pictures of it?

Comment: @EliasLind please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask An image of the code cannot be copied or used by others easily. It has to be re-typed by the person looking to help you and they may choose not to help since the code can't be easily replicated, tested, or added to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to remove click accessibility for the child.

```
$('div.banner > *').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

And then, you can use the jquery selector for the `.unread` class to remove the class and replace `.dot` with `.read-dot`

```
$('.unread').click((e) => {
    let clickedElm = e.target;
    clickedElm.classList.remove('unread');
    clickedElm.querySelector('span').classList.remove('dot');
    clickedElm.querySelector('span').classList.add('read-dot');
    
})
```